# Renault Clio 3. Noise in steering wheel

Tags: noise, renault, steering-wheel, clio

My mother have a Clio III (y 2012) DCi. I noticed something strange.

I describe the issue here:

> Suppose the car is parked and I'm about to leave. When I turn the
> steering wheel it makes an unusual noise.
>
> The noise it makes is not crackling nor of high volume. Rather, I hear
> a kind of smooth friction, as if two smooth surfaces were rubbing
> against each other.

A mechanic told me that could be the first symptoms of a power steering breakdown. But I don't know. What the good diagnosis could be?

N.B. If another details are needed just tell me.

**EDIT : In [this link](https://app.box.com/s/oxkdrhwq7u1kyu5y3oeo0nk31mn11ajs) you can hear the upsaid noise (in secondes 2 and 7).**

Comment: If the mechanic was there and heard it, I would trust them. Without hearing it, we can only make educated guesses.

Comment: I didn't precise that, in fact, he didn't hear the noise, but my sole description...

Comment: okay - can you post a recording of the sound to help us.

Comment: I have just added the record to my post. You can check the **EDIT** part.